# Loop over property in Ant

Tags: ant

I would like to understand that is the following possible in Ant

- Read a property `eg : ${for.loop.condition}`
- Based on the above property value , create a for loop
- And loop dynamically create a string from that value

I have read on the ant-contrib task , but not so sure whether that would help me out.

Any examples would help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a variable where a list of values are concatenated to control the iteration, so you can decide what to do with each value. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214069/how-to-split-a-string-and-use-it-inside-a-for-loop-in-ant-script) it may help you to use the "for" tag.

You can also use the for-each tag to iterate through a set of values selected with a fileset tag.

```
<foreach target="target2Call" param="paramName">
   <fileset dir="${myDir}">
       <include name="**/mifilesFilter.*" />
   </fileset>
</foreach>
```

Here's [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467991/ant-how-to-execute-a-command-for-each-file-in-directory) about how to use foreach tag.

Comment: i've found you can't use param names with mixed case, only lower case works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use if and for loop like this :

```
<target name="mTomcat">
  <property name="property" value="xyz"/>                      
  <sequential>

  <if>
    <equals arg1="${property}" arg2="xyz" />
    <then>

      <for list="${list}" param="param" delimiter=",">
        <sequential>
            < do the stuff here with param >
       </sequential>
     </for>
  </sequential>
</target>
```

Comment: @YaP The original poster mentions ant-contrib which adds a for command.  http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html